# Repopulate select2 options on removing selected option on another select

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am using select2 where i am loading options in two select boxes using an array. when i select an option from dropdown1, some values in the dropdown2 should get removed.Currently i can remove the options from dropdown2 but i am not able to repopulate them with all the values as at the beginning. Also when the i deselect the value in dropdown1 all the values should the populate in dropdown2 as it was on loading the page.

Here is the code :

```
var data = [{ id: 1, text: 'select' }, 
        { id: 2, text: 'A' }, 
        { id: 3, text: 'B' }, 
        { id: 4, text: 'C'}];

$('#select1').select2({data: data}).on(
                'change',
                function() {
                          if(this.value== 1)
                          $('#select2').find('option[value=2]').remove();
                          else
                          $('#select2').find('option[value=4]').remove();
                          }
                      });
```

This code removes the options but when i again select any other option from select1 this options are not visible. Also there are lot of options with 7-8 dropdowns on the page. this is just an example what i am trying to do.

Any help is appreciated. Looking for an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to reload/reinitialize the select2 for 2nd dropdown when you want to repopulate the options?

Not sure if this helps.

Reference - https://select2.github.io/examples.html
$(".js-example-data-array").select2({
  data: data
})

like when you deselects from dropdown1, on its change event/function you can try 
$('#select2').select2({data: data});

Comment: Can you try to empty the dropdown and again fill it up? on particular event.

Comment: there are 8 dropdowns on a page. each one with atleast 5-6 options. so if i do that there will be lot of jquery code. that the reason i want something which should be just few lines of code.